# Multiple asterisks in wildcard certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

Is it possible to get a wildcard certificate with more than one asterisk?

For example, would this work?

- *.*.example.com

Or can we generate a certificate with only one leading asterisk, such as *.example.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain